# Thumbnails Not generated when sharing on WhatsApp

Tags: thumbnails

When I share my website link on WhatsApp, the thumbnail image is not generated in WhatsApp but the heading and content are generated. I cannot determine what is causing this. I have tried disabling apps and everything. Is this an issue with WordPress? It used to work perfectly fine a long time back but now it doesn’t. Please help.

This is my website link: https://engineers-forum.com/

Comment: Have you checked what WhatsApp requires on the page to display an image? Are you using a plugin to add that? Many services require certain `meta` tags on the site to tell it what image to display, but WordPress doesn't necessarily output these by default. You might need a plugin.